# Questions on TWCS compaction in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

1. In order to use TWCS in C* 2.2, I built jar from the https://github.com/jeffjirsa/twcs codeline and added it to my lib directory. Cqlsh works fine with TWCS, but looks like the python driver doesn't recognize the new class and config options. I set the CLASSPATH in `cassandra-env.sh` to the lib directory.

   ```
   import ssl
   from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
   from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider

   ap = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='cassandra', password='cassandra')
   ip = '127.0.0.1'
   ca_path = '/a/ca.pem'
   cluster = Cluster(contact_points=[ip], port=9042, protocol_version=2, auth_provider=ap, ssl_options={'ca_certs': ca_path, 'cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED})
   session = cluster.connect()

   create_statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.agg_errors(time timestamp, timeid uuid, datacenter text,app_name text, error_message text, PRIMARY KEY(time,timeid))  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timeid DESC)  AND  default_time_to_live = 86400 AND compaction = { 'class':'com.jeffjirsa.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy','compaction_window_unit': 'HOURS','compaction_window_size': '1' , 'unchecked_tombstone_compaction':'true'} AND gc_grace_seconds = '43200'"

   session.execute(create_statement)
   ```

I get an error as :

```
    ConfigurationException: Failed to validate compaction options: {compaction_window_unit=HOURS, compaction_window_size=2}
```

Also, on further debugging, I noticed that this behavior is not consistent. The above script works fine once in ten runs, rest of the execution throws above error.

2. Can I add the subproperties of STCS to TWCS, for tuning STCS behavior within a window?
3. My window size is considerably lesser than ttl, lets say window 1 hour and ttl 1 day, in that case are the expired SStables after 1 day removed from disk? What interval is this check for expired SStables done?
4. I have read in a blog post about `exprired_sstable_check_frequency_seconds` for controlling the above behavior? Can this be used to control the frequency of checks?
5. Any suggestions based on which I can choose optimal compaction_window_size relative to the ttl of the table?

Note:My Cassandr version 2.2.4. Version present in patch is for 2.2.5, I hope this should not be a problem.

Comment: Did you build off of the 2.2 branch or master? Can you include your classpath?

Comment: Thanks Chris, just checked that I cloned the master branch. On cloning 2.2 branch, it is working..

Comment: Chris, cqlsh works fine, but I still see this error when I create tables using TWCS via python driver script. Do you have any idea, how to fix this error in my python script?

Comment: That error is returned from C* not the driver. And cqlsh uses the python driver. Did you miss adding the classpath with the correct version on one of the nodes?

Comment: No,I have added the jar and updated classpath correctly on all nodes. That's why cqlsh always works fine with TWCS. But via python driver, when I create table it throws ConfigurationException.

Comment: can you include snippet of python code thats failing in question? Its the exact same driver cqlsh uses.